# Creating an Authentication Header in ExpressJS . Translation of Java to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, express, post, header

for the authentication of my Node Server (Express JS) with another API a separate header must be sent within the POST request.

Quote from the documentation:

> You need to send a X-Authorization-Ahoi header with this request. The
>   header value is an encoded JSON string that consists of the
>   `<INSTALLATION_ID>`, a random 16-character string as nonce and the
>   current date in ISO 8601 format.

Example from the documentation:

```
{
    "installationId":"<INSTALLATION_ID>",
    "nonce":"0wYWLarLDBrWU7B2I1Go4A==",
    "timestamp":"2018-11-01T11:32:44.413Z"
}
```

In the documentation of the API the following Java example is given which I try to reproduce in Javascript.

```
String installationId = <INSTALLATION_ID>;
// create nonce
byte[] nonce = new byte[16];
SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(nonce);
String nonceBase64Enc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonce);
// create timestamp
String timeStr = Instant.now().toString();
// create json string
String xAuthAhoiJson = String.format("{\"installationId\":\"%s\",\"nonce\":\"%s\",\"timestamp\":\"%s\"}",
                                        installationId, nonceBase64Enc, timeStr);
// encode encrypted header value
String XAUTH_AHOI_BASE64_URL_ENC = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding()
                                         .encodeToString(xAuthAhoiJson.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ));
```

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
const installationId = '<EXAMPLE_INSTALLATIONID>';

const nonce_tmp = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const nonce = nonce_tmp.toString('base64');

const date = new Date();
const timestamp = date.toISOString();

const  xAuthAhoiJson = JSON.stringify({installationId, nonce, timestamp});

const XAUTH_AHOI_BASE64_URL_ENC = base64url.encode(xAuthAhoiJson);

const url = 'https://banking-sandbox.starfinanz.de/auth/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials';
        const options =  { headers: 
                          { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(credentials).toString('base64'),
                            'X-Authorization-Ahoi': XAUTH_AHOI_BASE64_URL_ENC }
                         };
request.post(url, options, function (e, r, b) { console.log(b); });
```

For the POST request I use the [request-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). 
For the encoding in Base64 URL Safe I use the [base64url-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url).
When executing the POST request I get the following message:

```
{
"timestamp": 1543229480764,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Nonce is invalid.",
"path": "/auth/v1/oauth/token"
}
```

Now my question is: What is wrong with creating my Nonce and how do I fix it?
Or is it the API I'm sending the POST request to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to convert the `nonceBase64Enc` to string. You have done that in java but not in javascript.

Just add the `.toString('hex');` at the end of `nonceBase64Enc`

> Example : const nonceBase64Enc = Buffer.from(nonce, 'base64').toString('hex');

You are done now!

Comment: That's exactly what solved my problem. Thank you very much!